# Symbol for "is associated with"

Tags: notation

Consider the following hypothesis: X is associated with Y.

Is there a symbol to denote "is associated with"?

Comment: Can you define "is associated with"? If not, then no, probably not.

Comment: "is associated with" in what respect, is the association two way, or just one way?

Answer (score 1):

How about $X \sim Y$?

Alternately, what's wrong with just writing 'is associated with?'

Comment: It is neater to have a symbol

Comment: I think writing $X \sim Y$ implies that we're dealing with an equilivance relation most of the time, so it may be quite confusing. However, as I've also seen the notation "$xRy$" for saying that $x \sim y$, maybe the OP could just use the notation "$xAy$" for saying that "$x$ is associated with $y$".